# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS : Failed to update on reboot

Tags: updates, battery, reboot, firmware, fwupd

I have Ubuntu 22.04 on Lenovo ThinkPad T14 Gen2i. There was recent update that got installed, but while rebooting the battery died and I had to restart it again instead of letting the system boot completely. After I did that the battery stopped charging. I checked `fwupdmgr get-history` and it showed me this error with system firmware and battery. I have tried using `sudo fwupdmgr upgrade`, but it shows `No updatable devices`. What to do in this situation?

[image]